# can we have dynamic href value

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have a script in which URL will be updated by admin panel and it is stored  into MySql Database,
how to convert this below code into php and have a database call at href location or 
i have to use any javascript to solve this problem

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>H2</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--Link Of Product-->  
<a href="DYNAMIC LINK URL" target="_self">
<!--Image link-->   
<img src="images/h2.jpg" width="190" height="220" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: you can start from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: @paka it's not even about ajax programming as far as I understand the question. http://www.w3schools.com/php/ There you go

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: http://w3fools.com

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I admire how you dislike w3cschool but keep in mind that the question isn't related to html/js and the sites offered from your link don't actually refer to any PHP tutorial alternative.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: In that case, surely http://php.net would be a better resource.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A better resource for language reference may be. w3cschool does a great introduction to php. w3cschool might not be the most up to date site on the internet. But php remains at version 5 for almost 10 years so I'm pretty sure w3cschool is giving a a good introduction to php5 for a while.

Comment: I agree with TJ Crowder - it is a great resource, as long as you don't take any of its certifications. Everyone learns differently, some people like to learn from the top-down, some bottom-up. It's not always accurate but it's a good **starting point** for beginners.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: I can't speak for the quality of the PHP information. The JavaScript and HTML info has serious flaws, which makes me just go another way full stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your reading your links from the database, you can proceed as follows. This example is made considering that your not using a MVC style framework.

```
<?php 
    $link = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM admin"));
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="_self">
```

Comment: As far as I know, mysql_* are deprecated and you should use pdo  or mysqli instead.

Comment: DevZer0 iam poor in MySql statements
i have a DB name admindb
DB table name admin
DB column name url
plz help me at syntax

Comment: i have updated the answer, i assume you know how to handle the connection logic

Comment: DevZer0 i have a small problem with it DB url1 is linked to another website iam getting something like localhost/<url link >
is there any way to solve it?.